# How to frame dynamic conditions in SQL when the value of interest itself is being queried

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

How to frame dynamic comparison in SQL when the condition itself is a field value on the table which is being queried.

Following is the sample kind of script I am looking for. This script is used to classify students into groups based on certain condition.

```
  DECLARE @GroupCondition TABLE
  (
      GroupID Int
      ,Condition NVARCHAR(MAX)
  )

  INSERT INTO @GroupCondition VALUES(1,'History < 80 OR Maths > 90 ')
  INSERT INTO @GroupCondition VALUES(2,'Science < 90 OR Maths = 100 ')

  SELECT 
    CASE WHEN G.Condition THEN 1 ELSE 0 END [GroupResult]
    ,S.Name,G.GroupID
  FROM StudentMarks S , @GroupCondition G
```

In the above select query can we get the actual condition to be framed of G.Condition??

Answer (score 3):

Note: there is likely a better way to do what you are trying to do here, but this works using dynamic sql:

```
--create table ##studentmarks (Name varchar(100),History int,Science int,Maths int);

--insert ##studentmarks select 'a',70,95,95;
--insert ##studentmarks select 'b',90,75,50;
--insert ##studentmarks select 'c',90,75,100;

declare @sql nvarchar(max)='';

 DECLARE @GroupCondition TABLE
  (
      GroupID Int
      ,Condition NVARCHAR(MAX)
  )

  INSERT INTO @GroupCondition VALUES(1,'History < 80 OR Maths > 90 ')
  INSERT INTO @GroupCondition VALUES(2,'Science < 90 OR Maths = 100 ');

select @sql=@sql+case when @sql!='' then ' union all ' else '' end+'select name,GroupID='+cast(GroupID as varchar)+',InGroup=case when '+condition+' then 1 else 0 end from ##studentmarks'
from @Groupcondition

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but it has a limitation.. If I have millions of unique condition.. then I cannot accommodate all in the sql variable as it can hold a only 8k chars at its maximum. So in this case I will have to loop. Is there a way to do this as a bulk operation rather than looping?

Comment: If you declare `sql nvarchar(max)` you do not have that 8k limitation.

Note the following query builds a sql statement that is about 30k characters and selects numbers 1-1000:

`declare @sql nvarchar(max)='';`

`with n(n) as (`
 `select 1 union all`
 `select n+1 from n where n<1000`
`)`
`select @sql=@sql+case when @sql!='' then ' union all ' else '' end+'select n='+cast(n as varchar)`
`from n`
`where n<=1000`
`option (maxrecursion 0);`


`set @sql+=' order by n';`

`select len(@sql);`

`exec(@sql);`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your StudentMarks table has columns 'History', 'Maths', 'Science' with corresponding grades, just rewrite your CASE statement like this:

```
CASE WHEN History < 80 OR Maths > 90 THEN 1
WHEN Science < 90 OR Maths = 100 THEN 2
    ELSE 0 END [GroupResult]
```

which will result in end query:

```
SELECT 
 CASE WHEN History < 80 OR Maths > 90 THEN 1
WHEN Science < 90 OR Maths = 100 THEN 2
ELSE 0 END [GroupResult]
,S.Name

FROM StudentMarks S
```

Comment: this can be done.. but in case of large volume of data it is not helpful.

Comment: how large? you should be ok even if it is a few millions. you might need to refine indexes, but overall the CASE statement is rather fast.

Comment: It is like each group will have different conditions and these conditions are to be applied for each studentMarklist.. Considering that it is done nation wide with millions of data it is not possible to hard code the condition in the case statement. It is expected to be built dynamically to do a bulk operation instead of looping..